# SP .trim() and jQuery.trim() are fighting

Tags: 2013, rest, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) to create my own views of information retrieved from a list and it is mostly working. Datatables is built on top of jQuery and relies on a lot of its features.

But a couple of different options or calls from datatables throw an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.replace is not a function...(init.js)
```

I've traced it down to jQuery and SharePoint both trying to polyfill `String.trim()`.

The jQuery version `$.trim(value)` will return a string with the white spaces at beginning and end removed. If you pass it a number it just returns the number.

The SP version of is in init.js and this is it

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, "").replace(/\s\s*$/, "")
}
```

The problem with this is that the jQuery implementation isn't expecting that `String.prototype.trim()` will have been altered and so `$.trim(number)` will convert to `number.replace(regex)` and there is no replace method on numbers.

The init.js file loads before jQuery and I really don't want to have to completely rework jQuery.

Is there anyway to prevent SharePoint from messing up $.trim()?

**EDIT**

So this is my really horrible hacky way of doing this that is really bad, but for the one page I need to get working today it seems to be working

```
Number.prototype.replace=function(){
   return this.valueof(this);
}
```

That puts a replace() method on numbers that just returns the value of the number. I'm sure there are soooo many reasons not to do this. If anybody has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: Worst part is that we don't have to worry about IE 8 anymore and all our browsers have a native String.trim() so the SP polyfill isn't even needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this on Stackoverflow because it had to deal more with how Javascript deals with prototype and things like that. With the help of folks there I added this to my page:

```
String.prototype.trim = function(){
  if(typeof this.valueOf(this) === 'string'){
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  } else {
    return this.valueOf(this);
  }
};

$.trim = function(e){
    return String.prototype.trim.call(e);
};
```

Oddly I couldn't just replace the prototype or redefine $.trim(). I had to do both.